# ¿como imprimir una variable PHP en variables longitud(lng) y latitud(lat) del api de google maps en javascrip para mostrarlo en mapa?

Tags: php, javascript

*esto es el resumen del php, ya que el codigo es muy largo, aquí estoy declarando las variables que posteriormente voy a imprimir en el archivo javascript,hasta aquí no hay probelmas, ya que las variables si las imprime desde otra página*

```
<?php
 include("conexion.php");
    $var = $hubicacion_lat;
    $var1 = $hubicacion_long;
    $var2 = $destino_lat;
    $var3 = $destino_long;
?>
```

*este es el codigo del api de google maps*
*acá en las variables lat y lng de las variables myLatLng y myLatLng2 de javascript es donde necesito imprimir las variables var1, var2, var3 y var4 de php, las cuales ya tienen valores numéricos asignados,los valores que se encuentran plasmados en lat y lng de javascript las coloqué para ver si funcionaba el mapa, pero ahora no logro plasmar las variables php en el cofigo javascript el api de google maps, soy muy novato con el javascript*

```
<script>
      //var hub_latitud = [<?php $hubicacion_latitud  ?>]

        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var labelIndex = 0;

function initialize() {

  var myLatLng = {lat: 10.484933, lng: -66.854268};
  var myLatLng2 = {lat: 10.483794, lng: -66.859836};

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:15,
    center:myLatLng
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);





  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
    title: 'Esta es la ubicación del usuario!',



  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng2,
    map: map,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
    title: 'Este es el destino del usuario!',





  });
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng3,
    map: map,
    icon: iconBase + ''
  });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Estás consultando a la API de Google desde JS o estás mandando una petición a tu archivo PHP? ¿Dónde se supone que recibirás la respuesta (en qué parte del código)?

Comment: hola padre, estoy consultando la geolocalización por la API de google maps de java script, pero quiero colocar unas variables obtenidas de mysql que ya están almacenadas en las variables var, va1,var2,var3 en php, pero no logro colocar esas variables de php dentro de las variables mylatlng y mylatlng1 en javascript

Comment: Si entendí bien el contexto es el siguente: quieres lanzar una consulta a la API de Google desde Javascript, pero para lanzarla necesitas datos que están en la base de datos. Si es así, te recomiendo que usas Ajax para traer los datos que están en el servidor (si son datos dinámicos). Si son datos fijos podrías cargarlos directamente al momento de abrir la página.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres imprimir una variable de **PHP** dentro del código de **JS** así como es tu caso puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var hub_latitud  = "<?= $var ?>";
var hub_longitud = "<?= $var1 ?>";
```

Pero como son cordenadas puedes hacerlo por medio de:

```
var hub_latitud   = parseFloat('<?= $var ?>');
var hub_longitud  = parseFloat('<?= $var1 ?>');
```

Con eso no deberías de tener problema alguno para usar tus variables **JS**.

Comment: ok, gracias bro, pero como introduzco las variables hub_latitud y hub_longitud en las variables var mylatlng (var myLatLng = {lat: 10.484933, lng: -66.854268}; ) y variable mylatlng2(var myLatLng2 = {lat: 10.484933, lng: -66.854268};) ? gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Nadamas cambia donde están los números de latitud y longitud por el nombre de las variables en lugar de {lat: 10.484933 pon {lat: hub_latitud, te debe de funcionar por que ya son variables js.

Answer (score 0):

en la variable `$enlace` se puede ver como manda al mapa con la longitud y latitud

codigo html

```
<div>
                <h1>Acceder a la ubicación con JavaScript</h1>
                <a class="ubicacion">Obtener Ubicacion</a>
                <br>
                <strong>Latitud: </strong> <input type="text" id="latitud">
                <br>
                <strong>Longitud: </strong> <input type="text" id="longitud"></p>
                <br>
                <a target="_blank" id="enlace" href="#">Abrir en Google Maps</a>
            </div>
```

codigo js con uso de jquery

```
$("a.ubicacion").click(function(){
   const onUbicacionConcedida = ubicacion => {
        const coordenadas = ubicacion.coords;
        $latitud = coordenadas.latitude;
        $longitud = coordenadas.longitude;
        $enlace = `https://www.google.com/maps/@${coordenadas.latitude},${coordenadas.longitude},20z`;
         console.log($latitud,$longitud,$enlace);
         $("#latitud").val($latitud);
         $("#longitud").val($longitud);
         $('#enlace').attr('href',$enlace);
    }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onUbicacionConcedida);
  });
```